# Find the limit with floor sequence or prove that it doesn't exist

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I need to find the limits of these 2 sequences or prove that they don't exist.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-5\left\lfloor\frac x5\right\rfloor\right)$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-5\left\lfloor \frac x5\right\rfloor}x$$
But I don't know how to get rid of the floor here.
I know I should use somehow this inequality. $\frac{x}{5} -1 \leq \left \lfloor \frac{x}{5} \right \rfloor \leq \frac{x}{5}$
But I'm not sure how to do it right.
And how to define in any sequence if the limit exist or not?
Thank you!

Comment: Hint: The second limit exists and is equal to 0, the first doesn't. To show that the first doesn't exist, consider $x=5n$ and $x=5n+1$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. To show that the second is 0, use your inequalities and estimate the fraction from above and below. Then let $x\to\infty$ on these bounds.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just have a question about the 1st one. So if I consider x=5n, the limit of the sequence will be equal to 0 in this case. And if I take x=5n+1, the limit will be equal to 1. So these limits are not the same, and it proves that the limit does not exist, right?

Comment: Exactly. Well done :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer of the first part. We  use the *[fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)* $\{x\}$ of a real number $x$.
$$\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor\qquad\qquad 0\leq \{x\}<1$$

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-5\left\lfloor\frac x5\right\rfloor\right)
> &=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-5\left(\frac{x}{5}-\left\{\frac{x}{5}\right\}\right)\right)\\
> &=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(5\cdot\left\{\frac{x}{5}\right\}\right)\\
> &=5\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}\left\{\frac{x}{5}\right\}\quad\not\exists\tag{1}\\
> \end{align*}

From the representation (1) we see, the values oscillate in $[0,5)$ when $x$ increases, so that the limit does not exist. In other words: Since the limits of the subsequences
\begin{align*}
5\cdot\lim_{{x\to\infty}\atop{x\in 5\mathbb{Z}}}\left\{\frac{x}{5}\right\}=0
\qquad\qquad\text{and}\qquad\qquad
5\cdot\lim_{{x\to\infty}\atop{x\in \frac{5}{2}\mathbb{Z}}}\left\{\frac{x}{5}\right\}=\frac{5}{2}\\
\end{align*}
are different, the limit (1) does not exist.